# Нужны хорошие эмуляторы iPhone, iPad

Tags: css, вёрстка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, хорошие эмуляторы iPhone, iPad для просмотра сайтов. ОС Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень сложно ответить на этот вопрос, поскольку не озвучены критерии "хорошести".

Для большинства типичных задач лично мне вполне хватает Google Chrome в режиме эмуляции мобильного устройства...

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант эмуляторы iPhone, iPad

http://iphone-emulator.org/